How to perform replacements containing square brackets with string_replace()?
I have a vector with two elements:
xx <- c("K[Phenylisocyanate (N-term)]SAPATGGVKKPHR", "A[Phenylisocyanate (N-term)]SAPATGGVKKPHR")

I would like to replace "[Phenylisocyanate (N-term)]" with "[Phenylisocyanate_Propionyl (Nterm)]", but only if the part to be replaced ("[Phenylisocyanate (N-term)]") is preceded by "K", i.e. in the first element only
So I would like to get c("K[Phenylisocyanate_Propionyl (Nterm)]SAPATGGVKKPHR", "A[Phenylisocyanate (N-term)]SAPATGGVKKPHR").
Performing this replacement with
str_replace (xx,  "K[Phenylisocyanate (N-term)]", "K[Phenylisocyanate_Propionyl (Nterm)]")

results in very unexpected behaviour:
[1] "K[Phenylisocyanate_Propionyl (Nterm)]Phenylisocyanate (N-term)]SAPATGGVKKPHR"
[2] "A[Phenylisocyanate (N-term)]SAPATGGVKK[Phenylisocyanate_Propionyl (Nterm)]HR"
could you perhaps explain how I should be writing this replacement and why I get this bizzare result?

The reason for the result above is that [ and ] are metacharacters in regular expressions, they mean 'match any character that appears inside the square brackets'.
To get around this, you can use the fixed() function to tell R that the pattern is not a regular expression.
str_replace(xx,  fixed("K[Phenylisocyanate (N-term)]"), "K[Phenylisocyanate_Propionyl (Nterm)]")


I should probably also have mentioned that the round brackets (  ) are also metacharacters.

If the neat solution with fixed() proposed by Shaun is not possible because regular expressions are required, you can escape the [ and ( with \\ in front of them on the pattern:
str_replace (
  xx,  
  "K\\[Phenylisocyanate \\(N-term\\)\\]", 
  "K[Phenylisocyanate_Propionyl (Nterm)]")

Output:
[1] "K[Phenylisocyanate_Propionyl (Nterm)]SAPATGGVKKPHR"
[2] "A[Phenylisocyanate (N-term)]SAPATGGVKKPHR"

You'll find very useful tips about it in stringr's cheat sheet here.
